# Как ловить Semetation fault c++?

Tags: python, c++, qt, try-catch, expressions

У меня есть код на питоне:

```
def mylen(list):
    tmp = 0
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            tmp = l[i] #пытаемся присвоить переменной tmp значение списка
            i+=1
        except IndexError: #если i вышло за размеры списка - завершаем цикл
            break
    return i
```

И я хочу перенести его на c++:

```
int arrlen(int data[]){
    int tmp, i = 0;
    while (true){
        try {
            tmp = data[i];
        } catch () {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Но я не понимаю что нужно написать в скобочках catch, чтобы ловить IdexError (Semetation fault/SIGSEGV)?
Возможно, нужно использовать throw, но какое исключение он должен генерировать чтобы быть пойманным catch?

Comment: Узнать длину массива нельзя.

Comment: Это совершенно разные исключения. SIGSEGV - это аппаратное исключение, а не исключительная ситуация. В принципе, в VC++ есть ключик, которые превращает аппаратные исключения в исключения С++ (ключик `/EHa`), но это как минимум не переносимо. Для этих ситуаций есть другой метод обработки - см. [`signal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal).

Comment: Нет гарантии, что при доступе за пределы массива у вас сработает SegFault/SIGSEGC, поэтому либо проверяйте сами через условие, либо используйте например std::vector с доступом к элементам через at (и ловите исключение)

Comment: Что до таких проверок, как выход за границы массива - простите, конечно, но нужно писать так, чтоб этого не происходило вообще, а не отлавливать такие ситуации через исключения. Я бы использовал `assert` в стрёмных местах во время разработки, ну, а в релизе - `#define NDEBUG` и все.

Comment: @Harry, я просто думал, можно сделать как в питоне и находить длину массива. 
 Спасибо

Comment: Здесь массивы совсем другие, они с собой свою длину не носят... Используйте, например, `vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. `try` / `catch` в С++ служит для перехвата исключений, бросаемых оператором `throw`. А выход за пределы массива и другие ситуации, грозящие SIGSEGV, в С++ обязан не допускать программист.

Если хочется допускать выход за пределы массива, но с генерацией исключения, то следует использовать один из стандартных классов `std::vector` / `std::array` и метод `at`, который будет генерировать исключение `std::out_of_range`:

```
::std::vector<int> items{};
try
{
    int tmp{items.at(::std::size_t{42})};
}
catch (::std::out_of_range const & exception)
{
    ::std::cout << exception.what() << ::std::endl;
}
```

Еще стоит пояснить, что `int data[]` в примере из вопроса не является массивом. Это указатель. Узнать, на какое количество элементов указывает не нулевой указатель (и указывает ли вообще) в С++ невозможно.